# Understanding Python inheritance and initialisation

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

In Python 2.7, consider I have the following code:

```
class Base(object):
    # Variant 1
    def __init__(self, records=[]):
        self._records = records

    # Variant 2
    # def __init__(self, records=[]):
    #     self._records = []
    #     if records:
    #         self._records = records

    def append(self, value):
        self._records.append(value)

class ChildA(Base):
    pass

class ChildB(Base):
    pass

a = ChildA()
b = ChildB()
a.append(100)
b.append(200)

print a._records
print b._records
```

If I use variant 1 to initialize my base class, self._records behaves like a class variable. Executing the code using variant 1 to initialize my base class, I get the ouput:

```
[100, 200]
[100, 200]
```

Using variant 2 to initialize my base class, self._records behaves like a instance variable (as expected). Executing the code using variant 2 to initialize my base class, I get the output:

```
[100]
[200]
```

What is the difference between these both variants? Why does variant 1 work different to variant 2? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your default argument is `[]`, which is a common pitfall with Python. See more in the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> Important warning: The default value is evaluated only once. This
>   makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a
>   list, dictionary, or instances of most classes.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with inheritance, class or instance variables.  Consider the next code:

```
>>> def f(a=[]):
...     a.append(1)
...     print a
...
>>> f.func_defaults
([],)
>>> f()
[1]
>>> f()
[1, 1]
>>> f.func_defaults
([1, 1],)
```

Default values for function parameters are evaluated only ones and stored within function object.  Each time `f` is called it operates with the same list.  Right as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As the others had put - this has to do with using an empty list as default value, not with class inheritance behavior at all.

The correct way to do it is:

```
class Base(object):
    # Variant 1
    def __init__(self, records=None):
        if records is None:
            records = []
        self._records = records
```

Therefore ensuring a new list instance is created each time the Base class is instantiated. The way you put it in your code, a list object is instantiated when your class body is parsed by Python - and that one instance of `list` is used as the default parameter each time the `__init__` method is run. As the objects hold a reference and change that same list, the change is visible in all other objects which share the `Base` class.